# invalid type for key Users, expected *_User, but got string

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, parse-platform

I am trying to save a data in parse for pointer field while i am trying i received the following error as

> invalid type for key Users, expected *_User,but got string

My code is as below

```
posts[@"Users"] = user1.objectId;
```

Comment: check the type of `user1.objectId`

Comment: And the error says the same, that it is not expecting a type of `String`, so `user1.objectId` can't be saved as a User.

Comment: That I know. I need to know how to save the values in pointer field. If not in string then how?

Comment: You dont need to extract objectId, just save the user1

Comment: @sasquatch Could you please guide me to save another user's objectId to the pointer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//  User1 is _User class object so directly assign it

```
  posts[@"Users"] =  user1;
```

[Saving object data in parse](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects)

Comment: @Muhamad Could you please guide me to save another user's objectId to the pointer...

Comment: add custom field in class in which you want pointer object. Colum pointer should reference the class you want  to  contain of that type